# Twilio Rest API

Tags: c#, twilio

I am facing issue with status call back event,  my status call back url is being called every time when call status changes but i am not able to get data
or call information. How can i get this data.

```
var call = CallResource.Create(to, from,
                url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
                statusCallback: new Uri("http://my-app.com/Home/Contact"),
                statusCallbackMethod: HttpMethod.Post,
                statusCallbackEvent : statusCallbackEvent
                );
```

Home/Contact url being hit by the application when call status changes but i did not understand how to get call information on this method? Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks) the api should pass parameters whenever the callback gets called. Does your callback accept these parameters?

Comment: [yes] @jegtugado

Comment: According to their docs you should be getting a number of callback parameters. I don't see any call information, can you clarify what you are looking for? You are using status call back and as the name suggest it gives the status.

Answer (score -1):

You will see a list of the key value pairs sent to your application in this document below.

[TwiML for Programmable Voice - Request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters)

You can extract them using the web development framework of your chosen programming language (i.e. Flask, Express, etc).